# How to use LabVIEW Property Node in C#?

Tags: c#, labview, measurement-studio

How to use LabVIEW Property Node in C#(with Measurement Studio) ?

Answer (score 0):

Google will answer your generic questions, this forum is useful for more specific detail oriented question.

http://labviewwiki.org/Control_References

This will also answer your other forum post:
http://forums.ni.com/t5/Measurement-Studio-for-NET/How-to-use-Property-node-in-Measurement-Studio/m-p/1317239

Comment: @ halfevil : The second link is my question( i.e, Posted by me)

Comment: I know, thats why I said it will answer your question THERE too :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question.  You should be able to use the standard C# dot notation for properties and methods, in the same way you would use LV's property and method nodes.  For instance (from [here](http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/epd/p/id/5274)):

```
using NationalInstruments.UI.WindowsForms;
private NationalInstruments.UI.WindowsForms.Slide noiseSlide;
private void InitializeComponent()
{
...
this.noiseSlide.FillBaseValue = -20;
this.noiseSlide.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 136);
this.noiseSlide.Name = "noiseSlide";
this.noiseSlide.Range = new NationalInstruments.UI.Range(-100, 0);
this.noiseSlide.ScalePosition = NationalInstruments.UI.NumericScalePosition.Bottom;
...
}
```